# How to redirect the root domain alone in nginx to another URL

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect the root path alone to a specific URL and other path to another URL.

For Example:

```
http://localhost/example should be redirected to http://localhost/example/index.php?route=common/home

http://localhost/example/welcome-to-this should be redirected to http://localhost/example/index.php?route=welcome-to-this
```

I tried this way

```
  location /example {
         rewrite ^ /example/index.php?_route_=common/home last;
   }
   location /example/(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /example/index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
location = /example {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/example/index.php?route=common/home;
}

location ~ ^/example/(.*)$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/example/index.php?route=$1;
}
```